# Have different size of cells on a UItableview to solve too long labels is a good idea?

Tags: ios, labels, data-tables, size

I have an UITableView with cells that contains title and subtitle. Sometimes the title or subtile is cropped because too big.

What is the best choice:

- let label cropped ?
- put title/subtitle on two lines with effect of having cells with different size on the tableview ? (visualy weird)
- Other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends.**

There are a few things you can do. In addition to the options you've mentioned already made (smaller size and multiple lines), you can also truncate the subtitle. See image below.

The image contains four cells;

1. Regular cell with fitting titles
2. Truncated subtitle
3. Smaller font for subtitle
4. Larger cell to fit subtitle

There's not one correct way. They all have pros and cons. My personal preference is to truncate the long (sub)title. This way your cells and font size stay consistent (pro). In my opinion this is worth more than showing the entire title at once (con).

[image]